# Stored Procedure with variable condition and error message

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In my procedure, the variable @year should take two forms: 1: If @Year=1, Select all years. 2: @Year= the entered year.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
CREATE PROC spProcName (@Year)
AS
BEGIN 
SELECT Year AS [YEAR], Item AS [ITEM]
FROM Sales
WHERE Year = @YEAR
```

I can make it work for @Year = 2013, but I don't know how to incorporate the @Year =1 to select all years. I'm guessing it would be with CASE.

I also have many other similar conditions with other variables, so I can't just create an IF statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Where Year = Case when @Year = 1 Then Year else @Year end
```

Comment: @user107242 Happy to help.

Answer (score 6):

Alternative to John's answer, but quasi-equivalent:

```
WHERE (@year=1 OR year=@year)
```

In this case it is best to add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` at the end of the query, otherwise the query won't be able to choose an index if it exists on the `year` column.

Answer (score 0):

```
--If you give value 1 it will select all the records from table year wise else if you give year like 2016 it fetches all the record based on given year
ALTER PROC spProcName (@Year int)
AS
BEGIN
  IF @Year = 1
  BEGIN
    SELECT
      [Year] AS [YEAR],
      Item AS [ITEM]
    FROM Sales
        ORDER BY [Year]
  END
  ELSE
    SELECT
      [Year] AS [YEAR],
      Item AS [ITEM]
    FROM Sales
        WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, CAST([Year] AS date)) = @year
END
```